# Как правильнее сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Наблюдение — чего-то или наблюдение — за чем-то?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

НАБЛЮДЕНИЕ - 1. (рассматривание, изучение) **за кем-чем**. *Наблюдение за животными; Наблюдение за звёздами.* 2. (при возможности вмешательства в наблюдаемое явление, его регулирования) **над кем-чем**. Наблюдение над подопытными кроликами. (Розенталь)

Comment: Есть еще наблюдать кого - что, например наблюдать больного( это тоже изучать, но есть ведь разница: наблюдать больного и наблюдать за больным). 
А еще наблюдать, т.е.внимательно следить глазами - наблюдать восход солнца.